# Autenticação e permissões dinâmicas

Tags: java, rest

Preciso disponibilizar em um serviço REST uma série de recursos, porém a segurança é dinâmica. Ou seja, um administrador poderá alterar as permissões de acordo com sua vontade.

Nas minhas pesquisas, só achei formas de autenticação onde as permissões aos recursos são pré-estabelecidos via arquivo de configuração/roles, ou seja, um usuário deve pertencer a um grupo (role) e este grupo tem acesso a uma lista de recursos. Isso não funciona para mim, uma vez que mais grupos podem ser criados a qualquer hora com permissões diferentes.

Uma forma que imaginei é enviar o usuário/senha a cada requisição e definir se o usuário tem permissão no momento da execução deste método, mas acredito que haja uma forma mais sofisticada de resolver isso.

Comment: Poderia dar mais detalhes da arquitetura? o cliente é o que? Móvel, web e/ou etc... quais tecnologias utilizadas?

Comment: @Mateus os clients poderão ser app mobile ou sites via javascript. Quanto a arquitetura, o projeto está começando agora (a parte REST) portanto estou aberto a opiniões de arquitetura. A princípio estou usando apenas Jersey num container Tomcat8.

Answer (score 0):

Nilson,

Uma das formas que resolvi em um projeto é a cada login por meio de um aplicativo móvel, a resposta de autenticação além de token de segurança e outras coisas mais, devolve um objeto Profile. Esse objeto profile é uma lista de ações. Essa lista de ações contém todas as ações importantes e transacionais capaz do usuário exercer no sistema ou não (explicitamente). Por grupos é complicado porque muitas vezes, é muito "granular" as características de autorização (quero dizer: muito detalhado o acesso em cada função / opção / tela / campo).

Quando uma ação é modificada (retirada ou adquirida) para aquele usuário, um PUSH chega e eu modifico isso no profile do aplicativo. O profile fica em todo tempo na memória da aplicação como um Singleton em única instância. Sempre que eu preciso, consulto se ele pode realizar aquela operação e concedo o acesso ou não/ exibo ou não o recurso. Isso evita fazer um timer com pooling (consumindo banda e servidor desnecessariamente).

Isso é na verdade um método que independe da tecnologia adotada. Se você usar por exemplo Spring com Java, terá algumas facilidades para fazer as transações controladas pelas rotas, criar um interceptador para decidir se o recurso pode ou não ser acessado.

Qualquer dúvida pode comentar e tentaremos ajudar em mais detalhes.

Comment: Como funciona a questão do token? O app recebe o token e o envia a cada request? Como eu intercepto esse token no servidor para averiguar se o usuário/token realmente possui permissão?

Comment: @NilsonUehara no primeiro login, o app produz um token e envia para o servidor. Na sequencia o token é derivado do primeiro e subsequente para cada requisição. A cada requisição no WS, antes de realizar, o servidor checa se o token enviado é válido, se for, processa a requisição e devolve um novo token. Tudo isso com certificado assinado para garantir a segurança no transporte. SSL/TLS. Mas implemente sem certificados. Inclusive o token pode ser usado para as pontas derivarem uma chave de criptografia. Nossa Nilson, vai longe a coisa kkkk, mas vamos conversando...

Comment: Mas a checagem do token é feito pelo método ou tem como criar um filtro para interceptar o header da request e checar o token?

Comment: No Header, sempre, para garantir a segurança. Antigamente, antes de Json etc, essa técnica era bem famosa, veja se ajuda a esclarecer um pouco esta troca de username-token: https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/13392/wss-v1.1-spec-pr-UsernameTokenProfile-01.htm

Comment: o que eu ainda não seu fazer é o interceptador ou filtro... como eu pego o header para fazer a checagem?

Comment: Esquece... é só usar um filter normal e acessar os parametros do header via HttpServletRequest.

Comment: @NilsonUehara sim...